# Get RSS feeds to hybrid mobile app

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, rss, hybrid-mobile-app

My project is to create a hybrid mobile app for a press Joomla web site.

I have the link of the RSS feeds (in XML), my questions is :

How can i get the feeds with Ajax because Ajax is not cross domains ??

My app will be converted by Cordova to get the "Apk" and Cordova get just html and js files , I mean if i use php (Curl), i must put the php file in a server and communicate with the php file by ajax and Ajax is not cross domains ...

I need your prepositions, i didn't start the project yet and i will work with (AngularJs+Ionic) or the JQuery mobile

Thank u in advance experts ;)

Comment: Phonegap has no cross domain issue. You can rise ajax request from localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first, then ask is the SO rule. You can make ajax call from your phonegap app to a server to communicate with php files. You shouldn't have any problem. I've used that technique, and no issue yet. `Ajax call + custom php service on server = all cool for phonegap.` And you should have `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml which normally set by default.